# Point of ihram for umrah

Tags: umrah

Salam,

Is it necessary to be in the state of ihram when first entering makkah or is it okay after i have settled in and get into to ihram via masjid al Ayesha? I am traveling from Canada.

Answer (score 1):

wasalam,

If you had decided to do umrah before traveling, and from the time you started your journey your intention was to do umrah, then you should enter ihram from the miqaat, because the intention to do umrah had already been formed.

So, if you're landing in Jeddah and going straight to Mekkah, then you should be in state of ihram before landing in Jeddah.  You should change an hour or two on the airplane before it lands.